# How to select records based on duplicate values of a column?

Tags: mysql, select, duplicates

- I have a 'users' table in mysql database.
- That table has duplicate entries of same user who has same email
  address as well but other information may vary.
- So I want to select all records of duplicate email addresses so that
  I can have all the rows of a particular email address alltogether.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: **PRECAUTION:** Logically speaking, you should put a **Unique Constraint** on the column holding email addresses , so that the duplicate emails could not be entered into the table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$product_groups = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products GROUP BY ProductId ORDER BY id");

while($productGroups_fetch = mysql_fetch_array($product_groups, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
     $product_images = mysql_query("SELECT ImageSource FROM products WHERE ProductId = 8");

while($fetch_product_image = mysql_fetch_array($product_images, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want the information of the users that has the same email adress of a particular email adress you can do it like this:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = "whatever";
```

guessing that you has a column named `email`. With this statement you will have all the records that has the same email.

If you want to know if a particular email adress is duplicate on your database you can use this another statement:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS numberDuplicates FROM users WHERE email = "whatever";
```

And you can use the `numberDuplicates` value to know if this email is duplicated or not.

Comment: Thanks. Your first suggestion gave me an idea. I used the following way:

Comment: Outerloop on resultset of this query: 
"SELECT id, UserId, FirstName, LastName, Email, AdminNote FROM customers GROUP BY Email ORDER BY id".

Inside outer loop:
"SELECT * FROM customers WHERE Email = 'test@test.com' "

Comment: @RoMo If you want to select all the columns of your table you can use `*` instead of the names of all the columns (I do not know if it is the case). According to what you have done you can try this without any outerloop: `SELECT * FROM customers WHERE Email = 'test@test.com' GROUP BY Email ORDER BY id;`. Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I had thought about it but I came to conclusion that I don't know email address to be fetched and had to fetch all. To get that unique email address I created outer loop to use it within inner loop for WHERE clause.

Comment: @RoMo Then I suppose that in the statement inside your outer loop you will have to use a parameter. When you put before `test@test.com` I though that you were using a specific email before doing outer loop. This is the reason why I suggested the second one statement.

Comment: @RoMo You are most welcome :) If it has solved your problem please mark it as accepted for future visitors of this answer. If it has not solved your problem, please post the code that you have written to solve your problem so new visitors to this question could see how to solve their problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE email_address IN 
(
    SELECT email_address FROM users 
    GROUP BY email_address HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
```

AND if you just want the count of users against each **email address** having more than 1 entries, run this:

```
SELECT email_address, COUNT(*) AS number_of_entries 
FROM users 
GROUP BY email_address 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```